# SQL select first row subquery of each group other record set to zero

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Please check blow query. I want below result through oracle query.
uPDATED COLUMN NAME AS PER QUERY

SQL select first row subquery of each group other record set to zero

**Query:**

```
SELECT a.SRNO, a.srno_dtl, a.REPORT_HEAD_NAME, a.current_gl_srno, a.Fixed_gl_srno,
    NVL((SELECT SUM(NVL(C.CURBAL,0))
    FROM GLMAS C
    WHERE C.BRANCH_CODE='2'
        AND  C.ACC_CODE=a.CURRENT_GL_SRNO
        AND (C.DATE_OP <='04-Sep-2017' )
        AND (C.DATE_CL IS NULL OR C.DATE_CL > '04-Sep-2017' )),0)
    AS MIN_LIMIT,

    NVL((SELECT SUM(NVL(C.CURBAL,0))
    FROM GLMAS C
    WHERE C.BRANCH_CODE='2'
         AND C.ACC_CODE=a.FIXED_GL_SRNO
         AND (C.DATE_OP <='04-Sep-2017' )

         AND (C.DATE_CL IS NULL OR C.DATE_CL > '04-Sep-2017' )),0)
    AS MAX_LIMIT
FROM INTER_BANK_EXP_HEAD a
ORDER BY a.SRNO,a.srno_dtl;
```

**Result:**

```
SRNO srno_dtl  REPORT_HEAD_NAME  current_gl_srno  Fixed_gl_srno  MIN_LIMIT  MAX_LIMIT
1    1         Axis Bank         330440           350130         -311510       -5012345
1    2         Axis Bank         330460           350130         -14028.2      -5012345
1    3         Axis Bank         330450           350130         -7734.76      -5012345
2    1         IDBI Bank         400080           350131         -390141       -6012345
2    2         IDBI Bank         200330           350131          10052.78     -6012345
2    3         IDBI Bank         330420           350131          347989.3     -6012345
```

I want this result:

```
SRNO srno_dtl  REPORT_HEAD_NAME  current_gl_srno  Fixed_gl_srno  MIN_LIMIT  MAX_LIMIT
1    1         Axis Bank         330440           350130         -311510       -5012345
1    2         Axis Bank         330460           350130         -14028.2      0
1    3         Axis Bank         330450           350130         -7734.76      0
2    1         IDBI Bank         400080           350131         -390141       -6012345
2    2         IDBI Bank         200330           350131          10052.78     0
2    3         IDBI Bank         330420           350131          347989.3     0
```

Comment: You may need to add some sample data that helps to demonstrate why you're getting the result you're getting and why you think you should be getting the result you want.

Comment: i want only camount only once in group other record must zero

Comment: i have used sabquery

Comment: What is the link between your query and the desierd result ? the name of column are not the same ?

Comment: sORRY I HAVE CREATED DATA WITH DUMMY COLUMN NAME

Comment: updated cOLUMN NAME @MrSmithGoesToWashington

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.SRNO, a.srno_dtl, a.REPORT_HEAD_NAME, a.current_gl_srno, 
a.Fixed_gl_srno,
    NVL((SELECT SUM(NVL(C.CURBAL,0))
    FROM GLMAS C
WHERE C.BRANCH_CODE='2'
    AND  C.ACC_CODE=a.CURRENT_GL_SRNO
    AND (C.DATE_OP <='04-Sep-2017' )
    AND (C.DATE_CL IS NULL OR C.DATE_CL > '04-Sep-2017' )),0)
AS MIN_LIMIT,

case when  a.srno_dtl = 0 
     then NVL((SELECT  SUM(NVL(C.CURBAL,0))
            FROM GLMAS C
            WHERE C.BRANCH_CODE='2'
                 AND C.ACC_CODE=a.FIXED_GL_SRNO
                 AND (C.DATE_OP <='04-Sep-2017' )

                 AND (C.DATE_CL IS NULL OR C.DATE_CL > '04-Sep-2017' )),0)         
     else 0
     end 
AS MAX_LIMIT
FROM INTER_BANK_EXP_HEAD a
ORDER BY a.SRNO,a.srno_dtl;
```

Comment: srno srno_dtl report_head_name current_gl_srno fixed_gl_srno min_limit max_limit
    1       1          Axis Bank             330440        350130     -311510.18      0
    1       2          Axis Bank             330460        350130     -14028.21      0
    1       3          Axis Bank             330450        350130     -7734.76      0
    2       1          IDBI Bank             400080        330420     -390140.92      0
    2       2          IDBI Bank             200330        330420     10052.78      0

Comment: Sorry, it should have been : `when  a.srno_dtl = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a table like in your result set. To get the desired results, use `LAG` function to compare column value with the previous row's column value :

```
select e.*, case when e.camount = nvl(lag(e.camount,1,null) over (order by e.id, e.sub_id),0) then e.camount - nvl(lag(e.camount,1,null) over (order by e.id, e.sub_id),0) 
            else e.camount
            end
  from INTER_BANK_EXP e;
```

[D e m o 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46fae/2)

You may use the following sql alternatively, if your `camount` remains the same for more than one bank ( thanks to @MrSmithGoesToWashington ):

```
select e.*, case when e.id = nvl(lag(e.id,1,null) over (order by e.id, e.sub_id),0) then e.camount - nvl(lag(e.camount,1,null) over (order by e.id, e.sub_id),0) 
            else e.camount
            end
  from INTER_BANK_EXP e;
```

[D e m o 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12fd4/5)

Comment: what happen if camount  is the same for two distinct bank ?

Comment: Thank You ! @barbaros-Özhan